# Android Поиск в списке

Tags: android, recyclerview, search, model

Есть Activity, Adapter, RecyclerView, CityModel. Хочу сделать поиск, который  искал бы среди 1000 элементов. Но чтоб при вводе букв, автоматически фильтровал список из 1000 элементов. Если у кого есть полезные уроки или статьи, буду рад посмотреть их. Заранее спасибо.
P.S. Я не хочу чтоб подгружались сразу все 1000 элементов. 
P.P.S. Мне просто нужна грамотная реализация по поиску.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792187/add-a-search-filter-on-recyclerview-with-cards

Comment: Могу оформить, как ответ с переводом на русский, если инглиш не осилите

Comment: Есть очень [подробный ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30429439) на английском SoF, но это "промышленная" реализация. Если нужно проще, достаточно в адаптере реализовать интерфейс `Filterable` и связать адаптер с виджетом `SearchView` (как в первом комментарии)

Comment: @metalurgus не, все круто! Спасибо)

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, будет неплохо, в т.ч. в деле добычи репутации, если вы сами переведёте ответ. Это может помочь другим посетителям страницы)